# Is linux LVM a good choice for 2 disks ?

Tags: raid-1, ubuntu-server, lvm, ubuntu-13.04

I am installing ubuntu server 13.04 on a machine.

I have 2 devices (hard disks) on it:

- 2 x 500GB on RAID 1
- 1 x 1TB

I was thinking about setup LVM, but I have no idea about how it works or if it's the best choice for my hardware configuration.

Can someone give me a explanation about LVM?

How can I decide between that solution and a more classic partitionning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVM is just an abstraction layer between partitions and filesystems.

You assign parititons/disks to **Physical volumes**, which you group into **volume groups** which you split into **logical volumes**.

I wouldn't group your 2 volumes into the same PV/VG but create a PC/VG pair for each volume (one for the raid arrazy, one for the other disk). But after that, you are free to split each VG into several LVs depending on your needs.

For example, one for /home, one for /var, one for /tmp... do what you want.

PS : If you're a visual person, type "LVM" in google images, you'll get plenty of schematics for better understandings.

Comment: Thanks! But, in this case, the simple/easy way can be the classic partitioning.

Comment: lvm isn't that complex. `pvcreate` `vgcreate` and `lvcreate` will do